# How to handle true/false values in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, boolean

I have problem where my JSON object has True instead of true and False instead of false. That is causing issues when I parse it to JSON. How do I resolve this issue?
In below script obj2 is not working as I have boolean True but not string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Creating an Object from a JSON String</h2>

    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    
    <script>
    const txt1 =  '{"device_state": {"device_name": "iPhone", "is_phone": true, "is_VOX": false}}'
    const obj1 = JSON.parse(txt1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = obj1.device_state.device_name
    const txt2 =  '{"device_state": {"device_name": "iPhone", "is_phone": True, "is_VOX": false}}'
    const obj2 = JSON.parse(txt2);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = obj2.device_state.device_name
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You resolve it on the server so that it provides valid JSON to the client.

Comment: @Raj What prevents you from assigning "is_phone": true, ?

Answer (score 0):

I can not see what prevents you from assigning "is_phone": true, but if for some reasons it is hard for you ,  you can change the code to this

```
var txt2 =  '{"device_state": {"device_name": "iPhone", "is_phone": True, "is_VOX": false}}';
txt2=txt2.replaceAll("True","true").replaceAll("False","false");
const obj2 = JSON.parse(txt2);
```